# Validating expression using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, lambda-calculus

Good day! I'm trying to create a program that accepts a Lambda expression from the user and what this program does is to check if it is a Valid Lambda expression.

**example - user inputs (λa.abc)a -> then validates**

my problem is that my knowledge of Regex function is very limited, I've been using preg_match to solve this but still not much of a progress. any help will be much appreciated.. Thanks :)

Well these are the rules of a valid λ-expression

> 1. a single variable = (single letter)
> 2. function application = (λ-expression)(λ-expression)
> 3. function abstraction = λ(variable).(λ-expression)

This is the code I did with preg_match

```
if(preg_match("/\((L([a-z])*.(([a-z])*)*)\)/", $getexpression, $match)):
print "Valid!";
```

does not really work that well

Comment: Please post more examples of these expressions, and how they're valid/invalid. As well as the code you've produced yourself so far.

Comment: really sorry about the formatting i am kinda new here

Comment: Please edit your question, to contain all of the information in a more readable manner.

Comment: @ChristianF there i edited it sir. i believe that would be readable :)

Comment: If you have `λ`, why you put `L` in the pattern? Also, `.` should be escaped to match a literal `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh sorry i just used L as an alternative to λ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as to ur second argument, any suggestions? :D

Comment: Now, what strings can we test against? Sorry, it is unclear. Here is a [regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/zX4jY6/1), please update with the right comprehensive samples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one for example λabc.a should return as valid because it meets rule 3

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/zX4jY6/2

Comment: single variables should also be accepted like: a or b
also
λa.λb.λc.abc

Comment: btw that tool is nice. thank you for introducing it to me :)

Comment: one more example to play with: https://regex101.com/r/lC3aA8/2

Comment: @mihutz here ((λa.b)a)b

Comment: What should match for: ((λa.b)a)b ?  λa.b ?

Comment: @mihutz what do u mean?? yes, those valid expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must confess that I didn't get too much from your definition of the expressions, since you basically said "an expression is a variable, or a collection of variables".
I'd generally recommend avoiding using the word you're trying to define within the definition itself.

That said, from reading up on Wikipedia and the comments, I think I might have gotten to what could be construed as a working regular expression for this:

```
// Basic definition: Lambda + letter == variable.
$lVar = 'λ[a-z]';

// Complex definition: Variable, possibly followed by variables,
// and closed with a letter preceeded by a dot or whitespace.
$lExp = "({$lVar}(?:\\.{$lVar})*(?:[ .][a-z]+))";

// Complete definition:
//    1. Only single  expression.
//    2. Or a parameterized expression which may contain
//       the entire pattern recursively.
$lRegEx = "/^$lExp|\\($lExp(?R)\\)\\Z/u";
```

That being said, I'm not 100% sure this can be tested with a regular expression. At least not fully. This seems to be the sort of thing that you need to write/use a [tokenizer](https://github.com/nette/tokenizer) for.